# Creating an HTML table from Excel sheet that summarizes repeated occurrences in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, html

I have a table like this in an Excel worksheet:

```
Mary Bremen
Paul Berlin
Anita Hamburg
Klaus Berlin
Peter Berlin
Conny Bremen
```

and I want the number of the city names counted and output in HTML:

```
Berlin 3
Bremen 2
Hamburg 1
```

preferably sorted as for the cities with the highest numbers. How do I do this?

Comment: Do U want summarizing data in Excel Sheet or as WEB page Table?

Comment: For a web-page table in HTML.

Comment: I can show you entire method in Excel then you can save the file as HTML ,, will this work for you? Please confirm through comments.

Comment: This would be interesting, but the task will have to be done again and again, so a script will be better.

Comment: then sorry since I don't know HTML coding !!

Comment: I found a solution in Perl. I will write it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page explains how to read in a CSV file with Perl and print the content sorted according to the values of some column. The CSV-Module is the important part, I was lacking.

https://perlmaven.com/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-perl